# Deleted by moderator for looking like an advertisement

Tags: discussion

My post to [this](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/47351/should-i-put-down-underlayment-when-putting-a-layer-of-tile-on-top-of-another/47354#47354) question was deleted 'because this resembles an advertisement'. I assure you this is not the case. Previous to some edits I would of understood it being done for the reasons of missing the point or off topic. Having already edited it to make it look less so, and an attempt to more closely answer the question, what **recourse can I take** to get a deleted-by-moderator post undeleted? Now that it is, comments are closed so there is no option for discussion (to reach the moderator) other than meta questions similar to this one that I've seen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should edit it so it doesn't look like an advertisement. Sorry if that sounds flippant but that's basically all you can do. The moderator would only have deleted it because it was flagged as spam by another user. In fact it was flagged by two users as spam - so that's at least three people who saw the post and thought it was spam.

Once you've edited it, flag it with the "other" option and we'll take another look and hopefully we'll be able to undelete it.

On the plus side I saw the original spam flag and declined it - but only after reading and re-reading it a few times, so I'm not surprised that other people also thought it was spam. It took me that long to realise that it wasn't an advert.

Comment: wow, maybe I should be doing advertizing.

Comment: @Mazura I nearly deleted the post as well. The only thing that saved it in my mind was that you've had other non-spam posts, and you had more than 1 rep.  Quoting from forums is bad form. If you need sources, use credible ones, not some other guy on the internet. Linking to specific products or services is also dangerous, and could easily end you up with spam flags.

Comment: @tester101, forums bad, noted, but I'd of stolen his quote without a cite. I figured at Home Improvement people would want to know what name brands to use. I sure would of liked it when I was nub. I hear you guys, thanks, onward and upwards.

Comment: @Mazura You can link to specific products. However, if most of the post is about said product, you'll likely get hit with a spam flag.  As your reputation within the system increases, so does the trust of other users. Once you gain a certain amount of trust, you're less likely to get the spam flags.  Though a lot of users put a little blurb at the end of their posts, specifically stating that they're not affiliated with a mentioned product.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the post was my acknowledgement that this post was very gray, with multiple community members thinking it was spam, but myself and others not believing you were a spammer. There's a -100 reputation hit if your post was actually verified as a spam message, so I tend to use the delete button as a middle ground when things are gray.

Things to do to avoid looking like spam, don't link to or mention specific products. Rather, try to focus on types of products. Links to other other forums also get a little more scrutiny because the spam could be posted in another forum. A post saying "No, don't use what you were thinking of using. Here's product X 5001 with a lifetime warranty, user testimonials, and if you act now there's a special 2 for 1 offer!" come across as a resurrected Billy Mays. As ChrisF suggests, edit the question to remove the links and product recommendation, and instead focus on the type of product you should use instead along with your own reasons for the recommendation, and then flag us to have a look.

Comment: The other answers better anyway. Thanks for the advice and getting back to me.